# Is this a real photo of North Korean kids?

Tags: photography, north-korea

I've seen this image multiple times thrown around in social media. It purportedly shows malnourished kids in North Korea.

[image]

I could not find a reputable source for this image using Google image search, only blogs. Is this image truly showing North Korean kids? What is the original source for it?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

[This photo was taken during the 1997 famine in North Korea by Justin Kilcullen, director of the Irish Catholic charity Trócaire](https://www.trocaire.org/news/spotlight-on-north-korea).

A [period news report](https://www.irishtimes.com/news/irish-group-of-politicians-shocked-by-starvation-in-north-korea-1.108557) says:

> The Irish delegation met a member of North Korea's ruling Workers'
>   Party Central Committee and two vice-ministers, said Mr Kilcullen.
>   They raised issues of human rights, arms sales and economic policies.
>
> Trocaire last month shipped its first consignment of aid to North
>   Korea, 3,750 tonnes of rice which has arrived from Vietnam.

Thanks in part to international support, the famine [ended in 1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Korean_famine). According to [numerous international organizations](https://www.academia.edu/25554321/Nutrition_and_Health_in_North_Korea_Whats_New_Whats_Changed_and_Why_It_Matters), North Korean living standards have improved significantly since 1998.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66921/discussion-on-answer-by-avery-is-this-a-real-photo-of-north-korean-kids).

Comment: FYI, the famine actually lasted [several years (1994-1998)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Korean_famine), with 1997 having the most starvation deaths. Flooding '94-'96, drought in '97, lack of established trade with other countries, and deliberately uneven food distribution made the famine as long and severe as it was (estimated 240k-3.5m deaths out of 22m). International intervention and better weather eventually ended it.